# How to pass authentication credientials to php application from a WPF app

Tags: php, wpf, cakephp, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

I have WPF app and Web browser control in it. I am opening a web page which is a  php application.
I need to pass my machine credential's to the php application.

The Web browser control opens a `[http://app/login.php]`. The user has logged onto the machine with his domain credential's.  The **PHP website uses windows authentication.**.

Both the WPF application and php site are internal application(i.e. same domain)

Comment: have you checked out [REST from cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/REST.html#rest)

Answer (score 1):

You have a CakePHP application and a login.php? Then there is something seriously wrong with it.

You need to get your current logged in users identity and pass that on to the php application.

See [Using windows authentication with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501729/using-windows-authentication-with-php)

If you're using CakePHP 2.0 you might find an LDAP adapter for the AuthComponent. I guess you can use google to find more, I don't know if this one here is any good or not http://www.analogrithems.com/rant/2012/01/03/cakephp-2-0-ldapauth/

Answer (score 0):

My answer covers the CakePHP part

Best practice would be to communicate using [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), between your wpf and cakephp. CakePHP provides a very easy way to connect your actions via REST. You will have to connect your authentication method using the REST.

Cake's documentation has a nice section on [REST from CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/REST.html#rest).