# In php validate remote windows user's credentials

Tags: php, windows, validation, command-line

On remote windows I am executing some commands in php, I need to validate windows credentials before actually execute commands. If credentials are invalid system should display error message without attempting to execute command.

Currently I am validating credentials like this

```
$check=shell_exec("wmic /NODE:\"$ip\" /USER:\"$id\" /password:\"$passwords\" os get caption,CSDVersion 2>&1  ");

if(strpos($check, 'denied') != false){return "Invalid_credentials";}
```

It is fulfilling my needs but I need a better way. Kindly help.

Note: I can't use ldap because it is not implemented.

Comment: In case of validating against an Active Directory you could use LDAP.

Comment: If the current method is fulfilling needs, how would you quantify "better"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using windows authentication with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501729/using-windows-authentication-with-php)

Comment: PHP LDAP would be the best solution. Also you can try with Pear::Auth package but it's currently unmaintainded

Comment: Generally speaking, there are no good ways of doing things when it comes to dealing with proprietary OS or Closed source tools.

Comment: @Dimi yes that is the issue with proprietary OS, in Linux I am simply achieving it via ssh2_auth_password.

Comment: LDAP is not implemented.